# Select query on 8 million records with greater and less than columns (Slow)

Tags: performance, mariadb, select

I looked through the posts but cannot find an answer.
I inherited this application so the response is **5+** seconds
Server version: 10.2.25-MariaDB-log SUSE
I added an index on 'LFT' and 'RGT' which helps a lot (down from 40+ secondes)

```
###explain<br>
+------+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table              | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                       | key     | key_len | ref                        | rows    | Extra                       |
+------+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | information_object | ALL    | PRIMARY,information_object_FI_14,information_object_FI_16,information_object_FI_18,information_object_FI_19,lft,rgt | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                       | 7859078 | Using where; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | object             | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                             | PRIMARY | 4       | atom.information_object.id |       1 |                             |
+------+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
```

Below my query:

```
SELECT object.CLASS_NAME, object.CREATED_AT, object.UPDATED_AT, 
       object.ID, object.SERIAL_NUMBER, information_object.ID, 
       information_object.IDENTIFIER, information_object.PARTNO, 
       information_object.OAI_LOCAL_IDENTIFIER, 
       information_object.LEVEL_OF_DESCRIPTION_ID, 
       information_object.COLLECTION_TYPE_ID, 
       information_object.REPOSITORY_ID, 
       information_object.REGISTRY_ID, information_object.PARENT_ID, 
       information_object.DESCRIPTION_STATUS_ID, 
       information_object.DESCRIPTION_DETAIL_ID, 
       information_object.DESCRIPTION_IDENTIFIER, 
       information_object.SOURCE_STANDARD, 
       information_object.DISPLAY_STANDARD_ID, 
       information_object.FORMAT_ID, information_object.SIZE_ID, 
       information_object.TYP_ID, information_object.EQUIPMENT_ID, 
       information_object.LFT, information_object.RGT, 
       information_object.SOURCE_CULTURE, information_object.SHELF, 
       information_object.ROW, information_object.BIN, 
       information_object.IMPORT_ID 
FROM `object`, `information_object` 
WHERE information_object.LFT<13702908 
  AND information_object.RGT>13702909 
  AND information_object.ID=object.ID 
ORDER BY information_object.LFT ASC;
```

This query takes about 2 seconds 
`` SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `information_object`, `object` WHERE information_object.LFT<13702908 AND information_object.RGT>13702909 AND information_object.ID=object.ID; ``

`` CREATE TABLE `information_object`
(
    `id` INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    `identifier` VARCHAR(1024),
    `partNo` VARCHAR(1024), 
    `oai_local_identifier` INTEGER  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `level_of_description_id` INTEGER,
    `collection_type_id` INTEGER,
    `repository_id` INTEGER,
    `registry_id` INTEGER,
    `parent_id` INTEGER,
    `description_status_id` INTEGER,
    `description_detail_id` INTEGER,
    `description_identifier` VARCHAR(1024),
    `source_standard` VARCHAR(1024),
    `display_standard_id` INTEGER,
    `format_id` INTEGER,
    `size_id` INTEGER,
    `typ_id` INTEGER,
    `equipment_id` INTEGER, 
    `shelf` VARCHAR(50),
    `row` VARCHAR(50),
    `bin` VARCHAR(50),
    `move_permanent` INTEGER,
    `import_id` VARCHAR(1024),
    `lft` INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    `rgt` INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    `source_culture` VARCHAR(16)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `information_object_U_1` (`oai_local_identifier`),
    KEY `lft`(`lft`),
    KEY `rgt`(`rgt`),
    CONSTRAINT `information_object_FK_1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
        REFERENCES `object` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    INDEX `information_object_FI_2` (`level_of_description_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `information_object_FK_2`
        FOREIGN KEY (`level_of_description_id`)
        REFERENCES `term` (`id`)
        ON DELETE SET NULL,
    INDEX `information_object_FI_3` (`collection_type_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `information_object_FK_3`
        FOREIGN KEY (`collection_type_id`)
        REFERENCES `term` (`id`),
    INDEX `information_object_FI_4` (`repository_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `information_object_FK_4`
        FOREIGN KEY (`repository_id`)
        REFERENCES `repository` (`id`),
    INDEX `information_object_FI_5` (`parent_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `information_object_FK_5`
        FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`)
        REFERENCES `information_object` (`id`),
    INDEX `information_object_FI_6` (`description_status_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `information_object_FK_6`
        FOREIGN KEY (`description_status_id`)
        REFERENCES `term` (`id`)
        ON DELETE SET NULL,
    INDEX `information_object_FI_7` (`description_detail_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `information_object_FK_7`
        FOREIGN KEY (`description_detail_id`)
        REFERENCES `term` (`id`)
        ON DELETE SET NULL,
    INDEX `information_object_FI_8` (`display_standard_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `information_object_FK_8`
        FOREIGN KEY (`display_standard_id`)
        REFERENCES `term` (`id`)
        ON DELETE SET NULL,
    INDEX `information_object_FI_9` (`format_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `information_object_FK_9`
        FOREIGN KEY (`format_id`)
        REFERENCES `term` (`id`)
        ON DELETE SET NULL,
    INDEX `information_object_FI_10` (`size_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `information_object_FK_10`
        FOREIGN KEY (`size_id`)
        REFERENCES `term` (`id`)
        ON DELETE SET NULL,
    INDEX `information_object_FI_11` (`typ_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `information_object_FK_11`
        FOREIGN KEY (`typ_id`)
        REFERENCES `term` (`id`)
        ON DELETE SET NULL,
    INDEX `information_object_FI_12` (`equipment_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `information_object_FK_12`
        FOREIGN KEY (`equipment_id`)
        REFERENCES `term` (`id`)
        ON DELETE SET NULL,

    INDEX `information_object_FI_13` (`import_id`),
    INDEX `information_object_FI_14` (`lft`),
    INDEX `information_object_FI_15` (`rgt`),
    INDEX `information_object_FI_16` (`identifier`),
    INDEX `information_object_FI_17` (`parent_id`, `lft`, `rgt`),
    INDEX `information_object_FI_18` (`lft`, `rgt`),
    INDEX `information_object_FI_19` (`id`, `lft`, `rgt`)
)Engine=InnoDB; ``

`` CREATE TABLE `object`
(
    `class_name` VARCHAR(255),
    `created_at` DATETIME  NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME  NOT NULL,
    `id` INTEGER  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `serial_number` INTEGER default 0 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)Engine=InnoDB; ``

Comment: Test ```INDEX `information_object_FI_20` (`lft`, `rgt`, `id`)``` - maybe it will help slightly more... and think about spatial (RTREE) index by ```(`lft`, `rgt`)```.

Comment: `information_object_FI_18` is effectively what the suggested `information_object_FI_20` is as `id` being the primary key is implicitly at the end of secondary indexes. How much of the table does `information_object.LFT<13702908` correspond to? and `information_object.RGT>13702909`? Look at [forcing the index](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/index-hints-how-to-force-query-plans/) to `information_object_FI_18` and observe the result.

Comment: With force index     1 row in set (0.93 sec)  Without force index 1 row in set (4.92 sec)  I will incorporate it into the code

Comment: I added force index to the code. It speeds up a bit but still not usable. It went from 5 seconds to about 3 seconds. The system loops through at least 7 of these iterations adding to 35s down to 21s for screen to come back.

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM `object`, `information_object` WHERE information_object.LFT<13702908 and information_object.ID=object.ID ORDER BY information_object.LFT ASC,information_object.LFT ASC;`
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  6851459 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2 min 9.55 sec)

 `SELECT count(*) FROM `object`, `information_object` WHERE information_object.RGT>13702909 AND information_object.ID=object.ID ORDER BY information_object.LFT ASC,information_object.LFT ASC;`
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1184507 |
+----------+

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.  LEFT-RIGHT schema design in inherently inefficient.  Since you are using 10.2, I recommend you experiment with redesigning the schema so that it is "hierarchical" and use a "recursive CTE".

(No, I don't know for sure that the change will be any faster.)

Meanwhile, I expect that this is the index that it is using; I don't see anything better:

```
(`lft`, `rgt`)  -- in that order
```